# Lyft deep link is not clickable on FB messenger

Tags: ios, deep-linking, facebook-messenger, messenger, lyft-api

I shared this deeplink on iMessage. It recognizes the deep link and if I click, it opens the app as expected from a deeplink.

> lyft://ridetype?id=lyft

If I share the same link on FB messenger it does not recognize this deep link. How do I get around this problem ?

I am on a iOS device.